# iOS:How to crop default camera image to circle

Tags: ios8

I am using the ios default camera in my application. I would like to change something the edit view that shows after the user takes a photo.Normally, it shows a rectangle to crop, but I would like it to show a circle how would I do this.

Comment: possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365819/ios-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-crop-to-circle-in-preview-view and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160854/ios-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-crop-to-circle-square-triangular-shape

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which might help you to create crop overlay:-

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController.viewControllers count] == 3)
    {
        CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

        UIView *plCropOverlay = [[[viewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1]subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

        plCropOverlay.hidden = YES;

        int position = 0;

        if (screenHeight == 568)
        {
            position = 124;
        }
        else
        {
            position = 80;
        }

        CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                               CGRectMake(0.0f, position, 320.0f, 320.0f)];
        [path2 setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

        [circleLayer setPath:[path2 CGPath]];

        [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, screenHeight-72) cornerRadius:0];

        [path appendPath:path2];
        [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

        CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        fillLayer.opacity = 0.8;
        [viewController.view.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];

        UILabel *moveLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 50)];
        [moveLabel setText:@"Move and Scale"];
        [moveLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [moveLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [viewController.view addSubview:moveLabel];
    }
}
```

Comment: this code make the default camera to circular but i want to open the default camera and after click the picture i want crop in circular shape.